# is there a way to only include factors that are significant at P<0.05 in a backward elimination in logistic regression

Tags: r, regression

When doing a backward elimination using the `step()`, is it possible to only include those factors that are significant, for example, at P<0.05?

I am using this line at the moment

```
step(FulMod3,direction="backward",trace=FALSE)
```

to get my final model.

Answer (score 6):

Answers to these questions give starting points

- [Logistic Regression in R (SAS-like output)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439248/logistic-regression-in-r-sas-like-output)
- [Stepwise Regression using P-Values to drop variables with nonsignificant p-values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701170/stepwise-regression-using-p-value)

In particular they point you towards `fastbw` in the `rms` package, which can be used in conjunction with `rms::lrm` (logistic regression).  They also explain why stepwise regression via p values is often a **really**, **really**, **really**, **BAD idea**: see also http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/stat/stepwise.html . There are a *few* contexts where it is appropriate (otherwise Frank Harrell, the author of the `rms` package and crusader against foolish uses of stepwise regression, wouldn't have written `fastbw`), but they are relatively rare, usually dominated by (e.g.) penalized regression approaches or by stepwise approaches via AIC (as implemented in `step`): see e.g.  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13686/what-are-modern-easily-used-alternatives-to-stepwise-regression and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20836/algorithms-for-automatic-model-selection

Comment: +1, this is good advice. 1 more link: it may help to understand *why* stepwise selection methods are a bad idea. An answer I wrote [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20836/algorithms-for-automatic-model-selection/20856#20856) may help to explain that.